# Hibernate execute multiple update statements within the same query

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two update statements. I want to have these two update statements in one query.

```
String hq1 = "update Table1 set xxxxx";
String hq2 = "update Table2 set xxxxxxxx";
Query query = session.createQuery(hq1);
int result = query.executeUpdate();
```

Suggest me the right approach. Thanks

Comment: This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24847466/update-multiple-rows-using-hibernate-criteria

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update several Columns in one Hibernate Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296499/update-several-columns-in-one-hibernate-query)

Answer (score 0):

The standard SQL syntax doesn't work in this way.
[The expected syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) for an UPDATE is :

> UPDATE table_name
>
> SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
>
> WHERE condition;

The column value have to be set with **one** specific value.
In your case, you want to `SET`the `featured` column with a value (`0` or `1`) that depends on the matching of the WHERE clause.
You cannot do it.

To achieve your requirement, you could use specific features of your DBMS (some provide a way to go further).
But to do it, you will also have to use native query and not Hibernate query.